# Как сделать перенаправление на поддомены

Tags: php, modx

**Добрый день! Не могу разобраться, как сделать перенаправление на поддомен...**

Есть запись в .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(ru|en)?/?(.*)$ index.php?cultureKey=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

В ней я определяю в каком контексте сейчас нахожусь.
Контекст обрабатываю простым кодом:

```
/* Определяю текущий язык в cultureKey */
switch ($_REQUEST['cultureKey']) {
    
    #Переключаю контекст */
    case 'en':
        $modx->switchContext('en');
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    break;

    default:
        $modx->switchContext('web');
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF8');
    break;
}

/* Очищаю GET-параметр чтобы не допустить появлении ссылки вида cultureKey=xy при генерации URL других компонентов */
unset($_GET['cultureKey']);
```

И получается URL такого формата:

```
Для ru - http://sitename.com/sity/
Для en - http://sitename.com/en/sity/
```

**Но никак не могу понять как написать правило в htaccess, чтобы сделать записи через поддомен формата:**

```
Для ru - http://sitename.com/sity/  =>  http://sity.sitename.com/
Для en - http://sitename.com/en/sity/  =>  http://sity.sitename.com/en/
```

Comment: никак не делать. субдомены к .htaccess вообще никакого отношения не имеют.

Answer (score 0):

Не трогайте htaccess - совсем. MODX отлично справляется с роутингом, если вы используете мультидомены в рамках контекстов. Задайте правильно настройки контекстов, настройте плагин для переключения(у вас выше есть) и все. Про мультидоменность много написано, погуглите, например:

- https://bezumkin.ru/sections/tips_and_tricks/2439/
- https://modx.ws/blog/blog-o-modx-revolution/razmeshhenie-neskolkix-sajtov-na-modx-revolution.html

Comment: В том то и дело, что в рамках контекстов я сделал разделение на ru и en. Но у меня есть города, которые находятся в этих контекстах и у меня не получается их сделать поддоменами 3 уровня...